# EF: Function evaluates properly while Lambda expression throws errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I was initially trying to use a Lambda expression to evaluate the SingleOrDefault function below but I kept getting the (Unable to create a constant value of type 'MVC_tutorial.Models.Movie'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context) error. I've then replaced the Lambda with an actual function, and suddenly the error disappears and the function evaluted properly. To my so far understanding, the lambda was supposed to be exactly equivalent to the *checker* function, but this understanding lies now in ruins. Can anyone please explain why one works, and the other doesn't?

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public IHttpActionResult RentMovie(NewRentalDTO newRentalDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == newRentalDTO.CustomerId);

            var movieList = _context.Movies.Where(c => newRentalDTO.MovieIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();

            foreach (Movie movie in movieList)
            {
                var rental = new Rental()
                {
                    DateRented = DateTime.Now,
                    Movie = movie,
                    Customer = customer

                };

                _context.Rentals.Add(rental);

                bool checker(Movie film)
                {
                    return movie == film;
                }
//lambda equivalent used in place of checker: c => c==movie
                var movieInDB = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(checker);
                var result = (movie == movieInDB);
                //movieInDB.NumberAvailable--;

            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (System.NotSupportedException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe try `c => c.Id == movie.Id`

Comment: That will work, yes, but im looking to understand why comparining full objects doesnt work through the lambda.

Comment: Because such expression is *not supported* by L2E query translator. When you make it a `Func` (delegate), then it's working, but gets executed in memory after loading the whole table in memory. Basically the difference between `Queryable` and `Enumerable` methods with one and the same name.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment, your lambda expression and the local method are _not_ the same. The lambda gets passed as an `Expression` object and the framework then attempts to translate that into a query, which fails. The method, it doesn't even bother. It just pulls everything into memory and runs it there, because the method _isn't_ interpreted as an `Expression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are paying a big performance penalty by using the function. The query must retrieve all objects and compare them.

If you use a lambda but only compare by Id, it can be converted into a query that just checks for a match based in Id and doesn't load all the movies into memory.

Comment: Thanks! This along with the comments above, are what I was looking for.